# How to divide multiple values of one category in a data frame from the corresponding single values of same category in another data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have one data frame, say data1. Its first column contains category types (say A, B, C).

```
data1 = [["A", 5, 6], ["B", 7, 3], ["C", 9, 6], ["B", 2, 8], ["A", 4, 8], ["C", 8, 1], ["B", 1, 0]]
```

Now I want to divide (or multiply or both) each value of one category in data1 from the corresponding value in data2 and to store it in data3. data2 is of the form.

```
data 2= [["A", 5, 8], ["B", 7, 8], ["C", 9, 6]]
```

Note that we have same columns in both data frames. data1 contains multiple rows of one category but data2 contains only one row of each category.

In result data3 will contains values like this

```
data1 = [["A", 5/5, 6/8], ["B", 7/7, 3/8], ["C", 9/9, 6/6], ["B", 2/7, 8/8], ["A", 4/5, 8/8], ["C", 8/9, 1/6], ["B", 1/7, 0/8]]
```

Here 5/5 mean the resulting value i.e. 1. I wrote it this way just to show that each value in data1 is divided by corresponding value in data2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of both `DataFrames`:

```
data1 = [["A", 5, 6], ["B", 7, 3], ["C", 9, 6], 
         ["B", 2, 8], ["A", 4, 8], ["C", 8, 1], ["B", 1, 0]]
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print (data1)
   0  1  2
0  A  5  6
1  B  7  3
2  C  9  6
3  B  2  8
4  A  4  8
5  C  8  1
6  B  1  0

data2= [["A", 5, 8], ["B", 7, 8], ["C", 9, 6]]
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print (data2)
   0  1  2
0  A  5  8
1  B  7  8
2  C  9  6
print (data1.set_index(0).div(data2.set_index(0)).reset_index())
   0         1         2
0  A  1.000000  0.750000
1  A  0.800000  1.000000
2  B  1.000000  0.375000
3  B  0.285714  1.000000
4  B  0.142857  0.000000
5  C  1.000000  1.000000
6  C  0.888889  0.166667
```

If some values of first column are missing in second `DataFrame`, get `NaN`, so need parameter `fill_value=1`:

```
data1 = [["A", 5, 6], ["B", 7, 3], ["C", 9, 6],
         ["B", 2, 8], ["A", 4, 8], ["C", 8, 1], ["B", 1, 0]]
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print (data1)
   0  1  2
0  A  5  6
1  B  7  3
2  C  9  6
3  B  2  8
4  A  4  8
5  C  8  1
6  B  1  0

data2= [["A", 5, 8], ["B", 7, 8]]
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print (data2)
   0  1  2
0  A  5  8
1  B  7  8
```

---

```
print (data1.set_index(0).div(data2.set_index(0)).reset_index())
   0         1      2
0  A  1.000000  0.750
1  A  0.800000  1.000
2  B  1.000000  0.375
3  B  0.285714  1.000
4  B  0.142857  0.000
5  C       NaN    NaN
6  C       NaN    NaN

print (data1.set_index(0).div(data2.set_index(0), fill_value=1).reset_index())
   0         1      2
0  A  1.000000  0.750
1  A  0.800000  1.000
2  B  1.000000  0.375
3  B  0.285714  1.000
4  B  0.142857  0.000
5  C  9.000000  6.000
6  C  8.000000  1.000
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) has to be used?

Comment: `dfnew = df.copy()` I think

Comment: Thanks @ jezrael. Now I have copied the same data in the csv file and reading it by using the following command inData = pd.read_csv("data/test/data1.csv", ",", usecols=[0,1,2]); It returns the same output like you when I use print. Now I use the command data2 = data1.groupby('0').max(); to get data2. but it does not generate the same output as yours and after that division also generates errors. Could you plz help?

Comment: Try add as_index=False like `data2 = data1.groupby('0', as_index=False).max()`

Comment: or add reset_index() like `data2 = data1.groupby('0').max().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *data2* to form a subset of the values present in *data1*, you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join to preserve the order while grouping and dividing them.

```
res_df = df1.merge(df2, on=[0], how='left')
a = np.column_stack((res_df.iloc[:,0], res_df.iloc[:,1:3].values/res_df.iloc[:,3:].values))
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

[image]